# An open set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

It might be a silly question but I don't know the answer and I really want to know about it.

Let $A$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Can we always find $\eta >0$ so that for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $B(x,\eta)\subseteq A$?

I think it is true. Since every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is an open interval, so we can find an open ball contained in the open interval.

Comment: Well let A=(0,0.0000001) and Let x = -5,673,546,213,879,486,290,345.  Do you still think it's true?

Comment: @fleablood This is a very nice example.

Answer (score 2):

No this is not true. Take for example $A=(0,1)$ and $x=2$. Then you won't find any ball centered in $x$ that is contained in $A$.

Besides, an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is not necessarily an open interval. For exemple $(0,1)\cup (4,5)$ is open and is not an interval. But you can show that an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a union of such intervals.

What is true is that is $A$ is open, then 
$$\forall x\in A,\, \exists\eta>0,\, B(x,\eta)\subset A$$
and this is a characterization of open sets.

Answer (score 0):

You make quite a confusion. Every open $connex$ set in $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval, therefore, every open set is an union of intervals.

And for your question, the answer is obviously no, because you wanna be able to choose "any $x\in\mathbb{R}$".
The real statement is that for $A$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, and for all $x\in A$, you can always find an $\eta>0$ such that $B(x,\eta)\subset A$.

The mistake you made was to choose $\eta$ before choosing $x$, what make the statement false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want almost the exact oposite.  For every x in **A**  !!!not!!! every x in **R** this is true.  That would be silly as x in R could be outside A.  Just pick x $\not \in A $ then x $\in  B (x,\nu) $ so $B (x,\nu) \not\subset A $.  And in your reason open sets are **not** intervals.  Consider the open set (0,1) $\cup $ (2,3).  It's the union of *two* intervals so it's not an interval itself.

However if A is open and x is in A then there will always be a $\nu$ so B (x, $\nu $) $\subset $ A because... that's the definition of what open means.